# User data not entirely stored in DB when using Spring Security

Tags: database, spring-security, spring-data

I'm using Spring Security with users to be stored in my DB via JDBC.
I'm also using Spring MVC.

RegisteredUser class:

```
@Entity
public class RegisteredUser extends User implements Serializable {

protected Long id;
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8500791712795093944L;
private String ssn;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public RegisteredUser (String username, String password, String ssn,
        boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
        boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
        {
    super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);

    this.setSsn(ssn);
}

public String getSsn() {
    return ssn;
}

public void setSsn(String ssn) {
    this.ssn= ssn;
}
}
```

Part of my security-config.xml. The tables "users" and "user_roles" exist in the db.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

            users-by-username-query="
                select username,password, enabled 
                from users where username=?"

            authorities-by-username-query="
                select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
                where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

When I try to save a new user, I got RegisteredUser information stored (i.e. ssn), but no entry is inserted in the users table, so username and password are not stored in the database and the entry of RegisteredUser is not referring any entry in the users table.

The way I save is by invoking save on the autowired attribute registeredUserRepo of type RegisteredUserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface RegisteredUserRepositoryextends
    PagingAndSortingRepository<RegisteredUser , Long> {

public RegisteredUser findByUsername(String username);
    }
```

In my db, I have this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `roles`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles` (
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rolename` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rolename` (`rolename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `roles` (`role_id`, `rolename`) VALUES
(1, 'ROLE_AMM'),
(2, 'ROLE_DIP'),
(3, 'ROLE_RES');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_roles` (
  `user_role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `authority` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_role_id`),
  KEY `FK_user_roles` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registereduser` (
  `DTYPE` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sn` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: So , this question is only about "cannot create a new `RegisteredUser`  by using spring data 's `PagingAndSortingRepository`" ? And it has nothing to do with spring security? If yes , please show your codes about how do you save  the `RegisteredUser`

Comment: I tried to clarify the question: actually, info about the RegisteredUser IS stored. The missing part is username and password, which are part of the org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User class. Also, since I'm extending this class from RegisteredUser, I would expect something like a foreign key from registereduser table to users table, but there is nothing.

Comment: Finally, I have one more class inheriting from RegisteredUser and adding an attribute: that attribute is stored in the db correctly (another table referring RegisteredUser by id). So, that's the reason why I believe the problem is spring security-related rather than spring data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem as follow:

1) Instead of extending the class User, RegisteredUser implements the interface UserDetails and adds username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired and accountNonLocked.

2) I created a BaseAuthority implementing GrantedAuthority encapsulating a String role (authority).

3) I associated 1-n RegisteredUser with BaseAuthority

4) I changed the queries in the security-config according to the new persistency structure derived by Spring Data based on my Spring Data annotations in RegisteredUser (including a @OneToMany with Authorities, also a managed bean Entity).